# async storage is not clear when we move to screen ios react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a `completeCart` function which invokes on click of checkout. It has to remove `cart_Id` from async storage and move to the home screen. After moving to the home screen then to cart screen it still has `cartId` from async storage, but when I refresh then the async storage is cleared?

```js
const completeCart = async() => {
  try {
    const cartId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart_id');
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/store/carts/${cartId}/complete`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // Include other headers such as Authorization if required
      },
    }, );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const text = await response.text();
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}, Body: ${text}`, );
    }

    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('cart_id');
    Alert.alert('Order created successfully ');
    navigation.navigate(SCREENS.HOME);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error completing cart:', error);
    // Handle the error, e.g., show an alert to the user
  }
};
```

Comment: sorry from my side the tab was on accidently , i forgot to see this , there was no intention to being ride